Does there exist a continuous injective mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose image is compact?
Does there exist a continuous injective mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose image is compact? I see from Wikipedia/Immersion that there are immersions that have compact image, but the immersion examples are not injective.

Yes.  Of course the inverse of the map will not be continuous.

@hardmath That was a mistake. I have corrected it.

The figure "An injectively immersed submanifold that is not an embedding." is what you are looking for.

@CheerfulParsnip ... and that one can map $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R^2$.

@GEdgar indeed.

I know it is not a homeomorphism, but it there an example? I have seen examples of similar things but the underlying topologies are not what we have here.

@W.EdwinClark the example is in the figure I cited in the Wikipedia article.

@Cheerful Parsnip Well, I saw that before but just didn't grok it. Now I do.

Up to homeomorphism, there are exactly five continuous images of $\mathbb R$, which are locally connected, locally compact and metrizable. All of them are subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$. Three of them are compact. See here.

@Ulli Thanks for the references.

Consider $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^3,\ f(t)=\left(\frac{2 t}{t^2+1},\frac{4 t(t^2-1)}{(t^2+1)^2},0\right)$
This makes an $\infty$ figure:

I only graphed it with $t$ from $-50$ to $50$ in the $XY$ plane, that's why the curve is not closed, but when $t$ takes all the real numbers you get the complete $\infty$

Okay, I understand now. This is similar to the example in the wikipedia article. I was just being dense!

@W.EdwinClark If this helped, you could accept my answer.

The figure on the Wikipedia page you linked to, captioned

An injectively immersed submanifold that is not an embedding.

depicts an example of a continuous injection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ whose image is compact. You can then compose with the inclusion of the  xy-plane $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ to get your desired map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$.
